# undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::~connection()'

Tags: c++, mysql, c++14, linker-errors

I am using [SQLPP11](https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11) for sql queries and results and [SQLPP11-Connector-mysql](https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11-connector-mysql) to establish connection with database.

And compiling my program using

```
g++ -std=c++1y main.cpp -I ../date -lsqlpp-mysql -lmysqlclient -lboost_system -lpthread
```

And here is the sample code i am using.

```
bool db_connection()
{
    auto config = std::make_shared<mysql::connection_config>();
    config->user = "root";
    config->password = "";
    config->database = "test";
    config->debug = true;
    sqlpp::mysql::connection db(config);
    try
    {
        sqlpp::mysql::connection db(config);
        std::cout << "Database connection establish...!!\n";

        std::cout << "Now executing a very simple select query in table using sqlpp11 \n";

        const auto g = changestreet::Goals{};
        for(const auto& row :  db(select(all_of(g)).from(g).unconditionally()))
        {
            std::cerr << row.goalId << "\n";
            std::cerr << row.goalName << "\n";
            std::cerr << row.goalAmount << "\n";
        }

    }
    catch (const sqlpp::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "No such database exits, you'll need to create it. \n";
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And the errors are

```
/tmp/ccxRheKs.o: In function `db_connection_cs()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x39d): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::connection(std::shared_ptr<sqlpp::mysql::connection_config> const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3c8): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::~connection()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x400): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::~connection()'
/tmp/ccxRheKs.o: In function `db_connection_nav()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4bf): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::connection(std::shared_ptr<sqlpp::mysql::connection_config> const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4ea): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::~connection()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x522): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::~connection()'
/tmp/ccxRheKs.o: In function `sqlpp::mysql::serializer_t::escape(std::string)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5sqlpp5mysql12serializer_t6escapeESs[_ZN5sqlpp5mysql12serializer_t6escapeESs]+0x2a): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::escape(std::string const&) const'
/tmp/ccxRheKs.o: In function `sqlpp::result_t<sqlpp::mysql::char_result_t, sqlpp::result_row_t<sqlpp::mysql::connection, sqlpp::field_spec_t<changestreet::Goals_::GoalId::_alias_t, sqlpp::integral, false, false>, sqlpp::field_spec_t<changestreet::Goals_::GoalName::_alias_t, sqlpp::text, true, false>, sqlpp::field_spec_t<changestreet::Goals_::GoalAmount::_alias_t, sqlpp::floating_point, true, false>, sqlpp::field_spec_t<changestreet::Goals_::GoalStartTime::_alias_t, sqlpp::day_point, true, false>, sqlpp::field_spec_t<changestreet::Goals_::GoalEndTime::_alias_t, sqlpp::day_point, true, false>, sqlpp::field_spec_t<changestreet::Goals_::GoalMonthlyContribution::_alias_t, sqlpp::floating_point, true, false>, sqlpp::field_spec_t<changestreet::Goals_::GoalStatus::_alias_t, sqlpp::text, true, false>, sqlpp::field_spec_t<changestreet::Goals_::UsersUserId::_alias_t, sqlpp::integral, true, false> > >::~result_t()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5sqlpp8result_tINS_5mysql13char_result_tENS_12result_ro
```

Here is the [build logs](https://gist.github.com/Shravan40/3377b3645ef7b1f1355b9eb02c693d81) of both the libraries on my 64 bit debian machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i have figured out the solution.

It was the problem with g++ version. Recent versions `g++-5` and `g++-6` have such problems, But when i get back to old `g++` version 4.9.2 everything is running smooth.

Comment: That hints strongly that libsqlpp-mysql was being built with a different compiler than the one you were trying to consume the library with. I'd wager the problem would disappear if you told CMake to build the library with `g++-5` or `g++-6` instead of the system default.

Answer (score 0):

"undefined reference to" usually means that the linker can not find the required library. Make sure your PATH environment has those libs sqlpp-mysql mysqlclient in scope.

Comment: Wouldn't the linker give an error if it couldn't find a library the user specified?

Comment: Well. The user may have installed several versions of the library, and something (path, .so name, etc) is confusing the linker.